# How to enable and disable the button in a checked event of checkbox in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a multiple check box in a grid. my code sample is as follows:

```
<asp:Panel ID="FeatureGridViewPanel" runat="server" Visible="true" Width="100%">
    <div class="topline"></div>
    <div class="linebreak"></div>
    <div style="float:left; width:90%;">
        <asp:GridView ID="FeatureListGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#666666" GridLines="None" Width="100%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="FeatureNameHeaderLabel" runat="server" Text="Feature Name "
                        CssClass="GridViewTH"></asp:Label>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div style="display: none;">
                            <asp:Label ID="FeatureIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FeatureID")%>'>' ></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <asp:Label ID="FeatureNameLabel" runat="server" CssClass="GridViewLabel"
                        Text='<%#Eval("FeatureName")%>'>' ></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="FeatureStatusHeaderLabel" runat="server" Text="Feature Status"
                        Class="GridViewTH"></asp:Label>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="FeatureStatusCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%#Eval("isEnabled") %>'
                        />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <div class="topline"></div>
    <div class="linebreak"></div>
    <div style="margin:4px; float:right;">
        <asp:Button ID="CancelAllChagesButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel All Changes"
        OnClick="CancelAllChagesButton_Click" CssClass="CCButtonEnabled" />
        <asp:Button ID="SaveAllChangesButton" runat="server" Text="Save All Changes"
        OnClick="SaveAllChangesButton_Click" CssClass="CCButtonEnabled" />
        <asp:Button ID="ChangePlanButton" runat="server" Text="Change Plan" OnClick="ChangePlanButton_Click"
        CssClass="CCButtonEnabled" />
        <asp:Button ID="UpgradeFeatureButton" runat="server" Text="Update Feature"
        OnClick="UpgradeFeatureButton_Click" CssClass="CCButtonEnabled" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

i just want to disable the SaveAllChangesButton and CancelAllChagesButton if there is no changes. i want to enabled the SaveAllChangesButton and CancelAllChagesButton when there is changes in the checkbox. to do so I have a jquery code like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('[id$=SaveAllChangesButton]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('[id$=CancelAllChagesButton]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $(".disabled").click(function () {
          return false;
      });
      $('[id$=FeatureStatusCheckBox]').click(function () {

          $('[id$=CancelAllChagesButton]').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
          $('[id$=SaveAllChangesButton]').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');

      });
  });
```

When there is no changes it is working fine, but when there is changes in some of the checkbox then the SaveAllChangesButton and CancelAllChagesButton  should be enabled but here in my condition this buttons are not enabled.
And when User clicks on CancelAllChagesButton  then the  SaveAllChangesButton and CancelAllChagesButton should be disable. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('input[id$="SaveAllChangesButton"]').prop('disabled', true);
   $('input[id$="CancelAllChagesButton"]').prop('disabled', true);

   $(".disabled").click(function () { return false; });
   $('input[id$="FeatureStatusCheckBox"]').click(function () {

         $('input[id$="CancelAllChagesButton"]').removeAttr('disabled');
         $('input[id$="SaveAllChangesButton"]').removeAttr('disabled');

   });
});
```

Comment: it should be `prop('disabled', true/false);`

Comment: The buttons are not enabled in the checked event of checkbox. again the same result.

Comment: only the document.ready section is executed. It doesnot fire the   $('[id$=FeatureStatusCheckBox]').click(function ()

Answer (score 1):

Bind your checkbox to the `change` event instead of `click`, and set the disabled property, not the attribute. You shouldn't need this `input[id$=""]` part in the selectors. You could instead do it like this. Much simpler. Here's a jsFiddle that demonstrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/xXfUp/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var check = $('#FeatureStatusCheckBox'),
      save = $('#SaveAllChangesButton'),
      cancel = $('#CancelAllChagesButton');

  save.prop('disabled', true);
  cancel.prop('disabled', true);

  check.change(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      save.prop('disabled', false);
      cancel.prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      save.prop('disabled', true);
      cancel.prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can Do Like This:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 var check = $('[id$=FeatureStatusCheckBox]'),
  save = $('[id$=SaveAllChangesButton]'),
  cancel = $('[id$=CancelAllChagesButton]');

  save.prop('disabled', "Disabled");
  cancel.prop('disabled', "Disabled");

  check.change(function () {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
  save.prop('disabled', "Disabled");
  cancel.prop('disabled', "Disabled");
  } 
  else {
  save.prop('disabled', "Disabled");
  cancel.prop('disabled', "Disabled");
}
```